# Is there a way to disable segfault exceptions in VSCode debugger?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

First off, I know that segfaults are raised no matter if you like them or not. However, I would like to ignore them in debugging.

For a class, I am deliberately raising segfaults and handling them in a handler. I would like to ignore the ones that I am handling (or all of them) as they make debugging difficult.

Comment: define your own exception, segfaults signal a specific case and mean the program is corrupt

Comment: My understanding is that mprotect only triggers segfaults and, because I must use mprotect, I believe this is not an option.

Comment: any C/C++ program that accesses an illegal memory location will generate a SEGFAULT. Array offset by 1, corrupt pointers, ....

Comment: I am not trying to avoid the segfault, I am trying to tell the debugger to not break on segfault but continue execution (i.e., to my sigaction handler)

Answer (score 1):

In settings, in Debug (On Task Errors) , there is a drop down menu to select, "control what to do when errors are encountered" . Select **"Debug Anyway"** option: Please see the screen shot:

[image]

I am using VS Code version 1.49.2

Comment: Hope this is what, you are looking for.

Comment: I believe this isn't related to exceptions during program execution, just during the build/launch process

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `debug (or Run)` tab on the left side of your VS code, and go down to where it says `breakpoint`.

[![The breakpoint]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpwS.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpwS.png)

And if you want your VS code to catch the unhandled exception, you can disable this `All Exceptions`.